# Trying to find a distribution for a multiple linear regression

Tags: statistics

So if I have a multiple regression model y = Xβ +  subject to a set of linear constraints of the form Cβ = γ, where C is m × (k + 1) matrix. The Gauss-Markov conditions hold and also ∼ $N(0, σ^2 I$). How am I able find the distribution of ($e'_c*e_c)/σ^2 $, where $e_c$ are the constrained residuals